# Dynamic App Icons iOS

Tags: ios

Is there any way to customize "You have changed the icon for AppName" message after UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("image") call or get rid of it at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly you can't because it is provided by the system, according to Apple's official guidelines.

> Note that your app icon can only be changed at the user’s request and
>   the system always provides the user with confirmation of such a
>   change.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to localize it maybe? Because I have all my app in Russian and this is actually not good to show messages written in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a solution to customize the text, but not sure whether Apple would approve it. We need to get the label:

```
func findTheLabel(in view: UIView)
{
    for item in view.subviews {
        if let view = item as? UILabel, view.text == "You have changed the icon for “myApp”." {
            view.text = "Hi, \n kind greetings from “myApp”."
            view.textAlignment = .justified
        }
        guard item.subviews.count > 0 else { continue }
        findTheLabel(in: item)
    }
}
```

And simply call it right after:

UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(iconName)  { (error) in
                    print(error)
                }

with small dispatch

```
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: false) {_ in
                if let view = UIApplication.topViewController()?.view {
                    self.findTheLabel(in: view)
                }
            }
```

Maybe someone would find it useful.